# Tutorials not passing NUnit Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, cuda, aleagpu

Today, I just came across QuantAlea and I'm trying to build and run their Tutorials. I first had to update my NVIDA GeForce GTX 670 driver to 9.18.13.5306 (5/27/2015).

Now I'm got the following error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'cublas64_65': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Therefore, I installed the CUDA Toolkit 7. (Note: my system doesn't have any other toolkit installed.) Searching my system I found cublas64_70.dll in the CUDA\v7.0\bin folder. Therefore, I'm assuming that cublas64_65 is part of the 64-bit CUDA Toolkit v6.5.

I noticed that the CUDA Toolkit 6.5 was released on Aug 2014 and v7.0 was release on March 2015. All the Alea.CUDA packages have a version of 2.0.0.3222, which were published on 3/23/2015. Therefore, it *appears* that these Alea.CUDA packages were built against v7. But for some reason my system is trying to access the 6.5 version... I think.

Anyway, How to do I get these Tutorials to pass the Unit tests?
Or How do I use QuantAlea with CUDA Toolkit 7?

Comment: The logic by which you have arrived at the conclusion that your libraries were built again CUDA 7 is flawed. I would wager you need to install CUDA 6.5

Comment: Why the 2 down grades? According to the answer below, my thinking was correct. Btw, I did end up installing 6.5 to get it to build. FYI: cublas64_65 means: cublas 64-bit version 6.5.  And like I'm to figure out you need to add  a special settings in the app.config? Really! The Turtorials should have be updated with these required change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in Alea GPU Tutorial project, it contains some tests of wrapper of NVIDIA libraries, the cuBLAS for example. And Alea GPU doesn't ship native of these libraries, so you need first do some configuration job to let it work. If you don't need to test these libraries, you can use Visual Stuido to build the project, and test other things.

By default, the setting is set to using CUDA 6.5 by default. You can change this through app.config (for 2.0.0.3222 version):
https://github.com/quantalea/AleaGPUTutorial/blob/master/src/app.config#L9
In the  element add:

```
  <aleaCUDASettings>
    <cuBLAS path32="yourpath\cublas32_70.dll" path64="yourpath\cublas64_70.dll"/>
    <monitor name="default"/>
    <!--<jitCompile level="Diagnostic" />-->
  </aleaCUDASettings>
```

Then rebuild the project, then it should work.